# Can I disable Bluetooth or camera or wifi of android device and allow enabling only through my customized app?

Tags: android, bluetooth, camera, wifi, enable-if

Below is the code for enabling/disabling but it does not disable the device settings.

I want to know how to disable bluetooth(Camera/Wifi) facility of android device and enable it only through my customized app. User should be able to on the bluetooth only through our app.

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter
            .getDefaultAdapter();
    boolean isEnabled = bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
    if (isEnabled) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bluetoothAdapter.disable();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Enabled",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bluetoothAdapter.enable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement BroadcastReceiver that listens to `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` ([link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)). It should disable it back and show some information about your lock to user.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();

        if (action.equals(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE,
                                                 BluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch (state) {
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                //do nothing
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                //do nothing
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                //disable it
                break;
            case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                //do nothing
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is a bit hacky, but this is the best you can do - like I wrote previously there is no way to disable this switch in Settings, as Settings are separate application and you cannot modify it, just like other apps cannot modify your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i am trying to build an app like App lock which lets user lock some apps. In the Applock app you can select bluetooth,camera and lock it with password. So i guess its possible to lock app. Any suggestions?

Comment: oh ok. got it. Thank you very much for the answer.i will implement the same and update here